# Topology in a proper class

Tags: general-topology

Topological spaces are usually modelled over sets. What happens if I try to topologize a proper class? Say, the class of all maps from naturals to cardinals or similar. Suppose I specify a topology on such a class by defining convergence for a net. What usual properties or facts may I lose? I would like to go on to take quotient spaces and continuous parametric families of elements etc. What could potentially go wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Topology_and_ordinals): "Note that if we are willing to accept a proper class as a topological space, then the class of all ordinals is also a topological space for the order topology."

Answer (score 1):

I'll just put here some ideas.

• Topology is usually defined by means of open sets. We should decide if we consider only subsets of the proper class or subclasses as well. More generally, often we shall decide which objects we allow to be large and which have to be small.

• Look at the category theory. A category is actually an ordinary structure like group. It is a partial monoid. But it is used in the setting when you allow large objects. So there lie many examples of this problem of dealing with size.

Comment: Good remarks, especially the first one. Thanks.